# How to open Select Data Dialogue from office content add in (Content App)

Tags: office-js, office-addins, office365-apps, apps-for-office, javascript-api-for-office

How to open Select Data Dialogue from office content add in.
Same Dialogue that open when

1. Insert excel chart.
2. Right click on chat.
3. Select Data.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer
[Office.context.document.bindings.addFromPromptAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/bindings.addfrompromptasync) do the trick

```
Office.context.document.bindings.addFromPromptAsync(Office.BindingType.Table,
        {
            id: "you id",
            promptText: "your text"
        },
        function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                if (asyncResult.value.columnCount < 2 || asyncResult.value.rowCount < 1) {
                    Office.context.document.bindings.releaseByIdAsync("DetailData");
                    myMessageBox.showErrorMessage("Insufficient detail data.");
                }
                else {
                    _detailDataBinding = asyncResult.value;
                    //do your work

                }
            }
        });
```